# execute cat command remotely using paramiko SSHClient

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am new to python and linux and trying the following

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.connect('server', username='username', password='cfwc')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command ('(cat /path to/a.txt |  cd /path to files ; ./script > b.txt )')
```

But something is wrong in executing the cat command. Nothing is being written to b.txt. I have also tried several combinations like,

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command ('(cat a.txt |  cd /path to files/script > b.txt )')
```

What do i miss here?

Comment: check is there any error occurs in your program...using `print stderr.readline()`

Answer (score 0):

Finally this solved my problem

exec_command("ssh machine 'cat /path-to-file | /path-to-script > /path-to-file'")